# Entity Framework include with a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have two entities, which are related, `ActiveContract` and `BudgetSource`.  I'm trying to grab all the BudgetSource which are marked as `isActive = true`, along with all associated `ActiveContracts` which are also marked `isActive = true`.  I've tired:

```
var d = budgetSourceRep.All.Where(x => x.isAcitve)
    .OrderBy(x => x.SourceName)
    .Include(z => z.ActiveContracts.Where(q => q.isActive))
    .Select(y => new EditSelectItemViewModel
    {
        Id = y.Id,
        SourceName = y.SourceName,
        DisplayOnNew = y.DisplayOnNew,
        NumberOfTimesUsed = y.ActiveContracts.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

but that gives me an error

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties. Parameter name: path

I then changed it to put the filter in the projection:

```
var d = budgetSourceRep.All.Where(x => x.isAcitve)
    .OrderBy(x => x.SourceName)
    .Include(z => z.ActiveContracts)
    .Select(y => new EditSelectItemViewModel
    {
        Id = y.Id,
        SourceName = y.SourceName,
        DisplayOnNew = y.DisplayOnNew,
        NumberOfTimesUsed = y.ActiveContracts.Count(a => a.isActive)
    }).ToList();
```

that works, but I'm assuming it's going to make a second query to do that?  If so, is there a way to do it in one shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> that works, but i'm assuming it's going to make a second query to do that?

No, it is not.  You can see for yourself by looking at the generated SQL for this query.

It is within the bounds of theoretical possibility for the query provider to have successfully translated your first query into SQL, but doing so is...hard.  This simply isn't a feature that the developers of EF chose to put into their query provider.  Instead you are forced to project out a collection of related entities in some way to filter them, you cannot use `Include` to do it for you.